# React-draft-wysiwyg contents not editable

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm new here. I'm currently building an editor using React-draft-wysiwyg editor. I was able to send my data to the backend and call it back. However, when I bring it back onto the Editor, I can't make any changes or edit the data. Below is my code :

```
let html = sendDescription.toString();
    let contentBlock = htmlToDraft(html);
    let contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks);
    let editorState1 = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState)
    let editorState = EditorState.moveFocusToEnd(editorState1);


  let [description, setDescription] = useState(editorState);
  const onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    setDescription(editorState);
  }
```

Note: Above,the "sendDescription" is my html data that I called from the backend

```
<Editor             editorState={editorState}         
                    onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
                    toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
                    wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
                    editorClassName="editorClassName"
                    onContentStateChange={onContentStateChangeJSon}
                    
                  />
```

Note: Above is My Editor

Can someone help me ?

I did Method 1:

```
<Editor> editorState={editorState} </ Editor >
```

Instead of Method 2.:

```
<Editor> editorState={description} </ Editor >
```

Because only method 1 was able to make the data displayed in the editor. When I did method 2, it was only showing an empty editor. If I needed to show more codes pls tell I'm really stuck.